# Optimizing Compound Mongo GeoSpatial Index

Tags: mongodb, optimization, indexing, geo

I have a MongoDB `$within` that looks like this:

```
db.action.find( { $and : [
    { actionType : "PLAY" },
    { 
        location : { 
            $within : { 
                $polygon : [ [ 0.0, 0.1 ], [ 0.0, 0.2 ] .. [ a.b, c.d ] ]
            } 
        }
    }
] } ).sort( { time : -1 } ).limit(50)
```

With regard to the action collection documents

- There are 5 actionTypes
- The action documents MAY or MAY NOT have a location with a ratio of approximately 70:30 for PLAY actions
- Otherwise there is no location
- The action documents will ALWAYS have time

The collection contains the following indexes

```
# I am interested recent actions 
db.action.ensureIndex({"time": -1}          

# I am interested in recent actions by a specific user
db.action.ensureIndex({"userId" : 1}, "time" -1}    

# I am interested in recent actions that relate to a unique song id
db.action.ensureIndex({"songId" : 1}, "time" -1}
```

I am experimenting with the following two indexes

- LocationOnly: `db.action.ensureIndex({"location":"2d"})`
- LocationPlusTime: `db.action.ensureIndex({"location":"2d"}, { "time": -1})`

Identical queries with each index are explained below:

**LocationOnly**

```
{
    "cursor":"BasicCursor",
    "isMultiKey":false,
    "n":50,
    "nscannedObjects":91076,
    "nscanned":91076,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans":273229,
    "nscannedAllPlans":273229,
    "scanAndOrder":true,
    "indexOnly":false,
    "nYields":1,
    "nChunkSkips":0,
    "millis":1090,
    "indexBounds":{},
    "server":"xxxx"
}
```

**LocationPlusTime**

```
{
    "cursor":"BasicCursor",
    "isMultiKey":false,
    "n":50,
    "nscannedObjects":91224,
    "nscanned":91224,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans":273673,
    "nscannedAllPlans":273673,
    "scanAndOrder":true,
    "indexOnly":false,
    "nYields":44,
    "nChunkSkips":0,
    "millis":1156,
    "indexBounds":{},
    "server":"xxxxx"
}
```

Given

- The geosearch will cover documents of ALL types
- The geosearch will cover documents with NO Location and WITH Location in a ratio of roughly 60:40

My questions are

- Can anybody explain why isMultiKey="false" on the second explain plan?
- Can anybody explain why there are more yields on the 2nd explain plan?

My speculative thoughts are

- The potential for NULL location is reducing the effectiveness of the
  GeoSpatial index.
- Compound Indexes of the GeoSpatial variety are not as powerful as standard compound indexes.

**UPDATE**
A sample document looks like this.

```
{ "_id" : "adba1154f1f3d4ddfafbff9bb3ae98f2a50e76ffc74a38bae1c44d251db315d25c99e7a1b4a8acb13d11bcd582b9843e335006a5be1d3ac8a502a0a205c0c527", 
  "_class" : "ie.soundwave.backstage.model.action.Action", 
  "time" : ISODate("2013-04-18T10:11:57Z"),
  "actionType" : "PLAY",
  "location" : { "lon" : -6.412839696767714, "lat" : 53.27401934563561 },
  "song" : { "_id" : "82e08446c87d21b032ccaee93109d6be", 
             "title" : "Motion Sickness", "album" : "In Our Heads", "artist" : "Hot Chip"
           }, 
  "userId" : "51309ed6e4b0e1fb33d882eb", "createTime" : ISODate("2013-04-18T10:12:59.127Z") 
}
```

**UPDATE**
The geo-query looks like this
https://www.google.com/maps/ms?msid=214949566612971430368.0004e267780661744eb95&msa=0&ll=-0.01133,-0.019226&spn=0.14471,0.264187

For various reasons approximately 250,000 documents exist in our DB at the point 0.0

Comment: In either case you don't actually end up using the index, as you use a "BasicCursor" - can you share how a document looks like as well? A few other comments: you don't need to use ``$and`` as that's the default and in general you want to use the ``2dsphere`` index instead of ``2d`` as it's a lot faster --- you will need MongoDB 2.4 for that though

Comment: Interesting, thanks Derick. I updated with a sample document. I wasn't sure of the exact benefit of 2dsphere over 2d, so I'll try that out for starters. I'm not sure I fully understand your "BasicCursor" comment.

Comment: BasicCursor means that no index was used at all... I will have a good look tomorrow.

Comment: Looks like until version 2.5.1 2dsphere does not respect the "sparse" option - which looks like it's useful since not all "Actions" have location.   https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9639

Comment: Added in the actual geo-query that is profiled above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played with this for a number of days and got the result I was looking for.

Firstly, given that action types other than "PLAY" CAN NOT have a location the additional query parameter "actionType==PLAY" was unnecessary and removed. Straight away I flipped from "time-reverse-b-tree" cursor to "Geobrowse-polygon" and for my test search latency improved by an order of 10.

Next, I revisited the 2dsphere as suggested by Derick. Again another latency improvement by roughly 5. Overall a much better user experience for map searches was achieved.

I have one refinement remaining. Queries in areas where there are no plays for a number of days have generally increased in latency. This is due to the query looking back in time until it can find "some play". If necessary, I will add in a time range guard to limit the search space of these queries to a set number of days.

Thanks for the hints Derick.